# Centering Text using multirow that overflows onto multiple lines

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, horizontal-alignment

I am trying to create a table where one column has multiple rows. This is very easy to do using the `multirow` package. However, if I specify a width for this `\multirow` and my text overflows, the second line of the multirow loses its centering. Here is an example of what I'm doing:

```
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{table}[!h]
    \begin{tabular}{ | c | c |}
        1 & \multirow{4}{100pt}{This one works} \\
        2 & \\
        3 & \\
        4 & \\
        1 & \multirow{4}{100pt}{This one doesn't work and loses its centering because the text is too long}\\
        2 & \\
        3 & \\
        4 & \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: I changed `100px` to `100pt` in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\multirow` uses the `\multirowsetup` macro before the text is actually typeset and, by default, `\multirowsetup` is defined as `\raggedright`. You can change this by redefining `\multirowsetup` (as I did in my example), or manually adding a `\centering` command in the last argument of each `\multirow` in which the text should appear centered.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} 
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \renewcommand\multirowsetup{\centering}
   \begin{tabular}{ | c | c |}
        1 & \multirow{4}{100pt}{This one works} \\
        2 & \\
        3 & \\
        4 & \\
        1 & \multirow{4}{100pt}{This one doesn't work and loses its centering because the text is too long}\\
        2 & \\
        3 & \\
        4 & \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```